# How to pass the second parameter to a Haskell function that takes 3 parameters?

Tags: haskell, currying

I am learning Haskell now, I am just really curious about this.
for example:

```
minus :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
minus x y z = x - y - z
```

what if I wanna pass y to the function [minus] first instead of x? I want a function [minus x 5 z]
I don't want this

```
minusy10 x z = minus x 10 z
```

if I have to define a new function to achieve this, I feel like it lost some "Haskell elegance".

Answer (score 12):

Your `minus10` is a very idiomatic way to do it; often this is bound inside a `where` clause so that it doesn't clutter the top-level API. `flip minus 10` and `` (`minus` 10) `` are also common choices. Those two choices work only for filling in the *second* argument; more generally, to fill in an *n*th argument, lambdas generalize better, as in `\x -> minus x 10`.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally, you're asking how you can write `minusy10` without explicitly naming its arguments. And, clearly, you also don't want to cheat by moving them into a lambda:

```hs
minusy10 = \x z -> minus x 10 z
```

What you want to do is writing `minusy10` in "point-free style".

This is easily done in this case, as suggested in the other answer, but in the more general case, you might want to refer to [pointfree.io](https://pointfree.io/), which will give you one possible way (but there might exist more) of writing a function in point-free style.

In this specific case, it comes up with the solution `flip minus 10` (which is possibly not the most readable one; I'd call `` (`minus` 10) `` more readable, instead).

On the other hand, and with reference to your feeling that

> if I have to define a new function to achieve this, I feel like it lost some "Haskell elegance"

it's worth taking into account that point-free style can make things less readable, if overused. In fact, even for very simple functions that you can read and understand in the blink of eye, such as this,

```hs
f x y = x + y*y
```

point-free style can result in something which is the opposite of readable (and actually even longer!):

```hs
f = (. join (*)) . (+)
```

So I'd say there's a balance between point-free style and "point-full" (?) style. Where's this balance? In my opinion one should target maximum *readability*, which is different from "parse-bility".

What I mean is that

```hs
subtract2 x = x - 2
```

is easy to parse, and fairly easy to read, but

```hs
subtract2 = (-2)
```

is even easier to read.

In your original example, the point-free form `` (`minus` 10) `` is fairly readable (but I would actually question the name you've given to `minus`, which makes me think of a binary `(-)`-like function, whereas it is ternary).

Comment: Thanks, that's very philosophical!

Comment: Not sure if that's a compliment, but thanks, ahahahaha :D